# Visual Studio alternative for a constexpr string

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

Visual Studio alredy has not implemented constexpr. Was the best way to refactor this:

```
constexpr auto DEBUG_FONT = "mydebugfont.ttf";
```

into a valid line in Visual Studio?

Comment: what's wrong with `const char DEBUG_FONT[] = "mydebugfont.ttf";`?

Comment: @frasnian, probably thats the best way when we don't have constexpr

Comment: re-adding as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
const char DEBUG_FONT[] = "mydebugfont.ttf";
```